# Decision tree pruning

Tags: cart, validation

I understand how pruning works in cross validation. But when the final tree is built, we will be using the entire dataset for tree training. How is the pruning performed then. I mean how do we see whether removing a leaf changes accuracy when there is no test dataset

Answer (score 1):

Pruning is performed in the same way, when using the full data set.
Unless you have not split the data set up into e.g. a training set and a test set (or use Cross Validation), you cannot test the performance of the tree in a proper way. I would thus highly recommend that you set some data aside to test on.

/Chris